# No guard flag after 3rd month

Tags: guard, flags

I am running a Tor relay for 6 Months now.
The first 3 months it was easy for me to get the Guard flag.
But since then (3 months) (I didn't change the configuartion) only moria1 is voting for Guard. (Guard probability 0%)

I have 1 MB/s bandwidth advertised, I got Fast HSDir Running Stable V2Dir Valid Flags and I am running for ~60 days straight.

Are there new requirements to be a Guard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently not every fast exit is also assigned the Guard flag. There was a change reported at [TWN of July, 30th 2014](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-weekly-news-%E2%80%94-july-30th-2014):

> Once directory authorities have upgraded, they will “assign the Guard flag to the fastest 25% of the network”. Some experiments showed that “for the current network, this results in about 1100 guards, down from 2500.”

If I'm correct the slowest guard currently has a bandwidth of 1.3 MB/s, so it is slightly faster than your server. If you could raise your advertised bandwidth to some value above it, you should get the guard flag.